# how can we go out from 4 inner for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, label, break, labelled-break

Hi
I am beginner in java and my program has 4 for loops: 
my program works like this that if `b` is `true` ,the element will be removed from pointList and `n` will be `n--`  and the I want to go out from all for loops and come again from the first for loop so `l` will be `l++`,how can i do this ? with break statement?

```
for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
  for (int i = 1; i < (n - 2); i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < (n - 1); j++) {
          for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
              if (l != i && l != j && l != k) {
                  boolean b = isOK(pointList.get(l), pointList.get(i), pointList.get(j), pointList.get(k));
                  System.out.println(b);
                  if (b == true) {
                      pointList.remove(pointList.get(l);
                      n--;
                      break;
                  }
                  else
                      System.out.println(b);
              }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! Is it realy neccessary to walk through in this way? Please [avoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality) cascading loops..

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551578/how-to-break-multiple-foreach-loop

Comment: Maybe you can describe in a few words what do you want to do? "remove l-th item if b is true". Your code contains syntax errors. Fix it, please, and clarify your question.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find 4 elements which meet some criteria. If you explained what the criteria was, perhaps we could suggest a simpler way of doing the same thing. e.g. perhaps sorting the list first might simplify the loops.

Comment: +1 - Nearly useless link, but I agree with the advice anyway.

Comment: One option might be http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-complexity.html , which near the bottom suggests you should try to prevent loops from nesting more than two deep.

Comment: Because of runtime-issues and structural behaviour (and others) you should avoid cascading loops. Using deep recursions can be a hint for bad design of your programm. Cant your function run without this recursion? (perhaps using functions, objects or anything like this to get your needs satisfied)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make use of a labeled break as:

```
      for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
 foo:    for (int i = 1; i < (n - 2); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < (n - 1); j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                    if (l != i && l != j && l != k) {
                        boolean b = isOK(pointList.get(l), pointList.get(i), pointList.get(j), pointList.get(k));
                        System.out.println(b);
                        if (b == true) {
                            pointList.remove(pointList.get(l);
                            n--;
                            break foo;
                        }
                        else
                            System.out.println(b);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it will break just the last three for loops and then it will start with the first loop and goes within those three for loops too?

Comment: You could consider any branching statement to be a "goto in disguise" I suppose. But they all have their limits and their uses. Even goto itself does, actually (state machines are a PITA without it).

Comment: didn0t event know that there are labeld breaks in java :D

Answer (score 5):

In a loop the `break` statement terminates the inner loop while `continue` skips to the next iteration. In order for these two statements to work on a different loop to the inner one you need to use [labels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). Something like this should work:

```
outerloop:      
        for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < (n - 2); i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < (n - 1); j++) {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                        if (l != i && l != j && l != k) {
                            boolean b = isOK(pointList.get(l), pointList.get(i), pointList.get(j), pointList.get(k));
                            System.out.println(b);
                            if (b == true) {
                                pointList.remove(pointList.get(l);
                                n--;
                                continue outerloop;
                            }
                            else
                                System.out.println(b);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the labeled break statement

for example here: [Branching Statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
String valueFromObj2 = null;
String valueFromObj4 = null;
OUTERMOST: for(Object1 object1: objects){
  for(Object2 object2: object1){
    //I get some value from object2
    valueFromObj2 = object2.getSomeValue();
    for(Object3 object3 : object2){
      for(Object4 object4: object3){
        //Finally I get some value from Object4.
        valueFromObj4 = object4.getSomeValue();
        //Compare with valueFromObj2 to decide either to break all the foreach loop
        if( compareTwoVariable(valueFromObj2, valueFromObj4 )) {
          break OUTERMOST;
        }
      }//fourth loop ends here
    }//third loop ends here
  }//second loop ends here
}//first loop ends here
```

Comment: taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551578/how-to-break-multiple-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2):

Use a labeled loop

```
for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
    loopa:
    for (int i = 1; i < (n - 2); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < (n - 1); j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                if (l != i && l != j && l != k) {
                    boolean b = isOK(pointList.get(l), pointList.get(i), pointList.get(j), pointList.get(k));
                    System.out.println(b);
                    if (b == true) {
                        pointList.remove(pointList.get(l);
                        n--;
                        break loopa;
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println(b);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

and then break from the labeled loop

Comment: it will break just the last three for loops and then it will start with the first loop and goes within those three for loops too?

Comment: Functionally equivalent to that from Brain. In that it will kick into the next iteration of the outermost loop

Answer (score 1):

```
again:
for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < (n - 2); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < (n - 1); j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                    if (l != i && l != j && l != k) {
                        boolean b = isOK(pointList.get(l), pointList.get(i),  pointList.get(j), pointList.get(k));
                        System.out.println(b);
                        if (b == true) {
                            pointList.remove(pointList.get(l);
                            n--;
                            break again;
                        }
                        else
                            System.out.println(b);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the other answers. However, I'd like to point out that an alternative to `exit` would be to just put that code in its own routine and use a `return` statement to break out of the whole thing. Your quad-nested loop is so complex by itself that it probably deserves to be in its own routine anyway.

I've worked on DoD jobs that required a [cyclomatic complexity](http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-complexity.html) of no more than 6 for any one routine (with some exceptions). This series of loops alone is 4. If you can't find a simpler way to do it, you really ought to chuck them in their own routine just to preserve the sanity of the poor schmucks who have to maintain this code.

Answer (score 0):

A first 'quick and dirty' solution would be to use a `stay_into_loops` variable and modify the `for` loops like:

```
 boolean stay_into_loops = true
 // here goes the first for loop
 for (int i = 1; i < (n - 2) && stay_into_loops ; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < (n - 1) && stay_into_loops ; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < n && stay_into_loops ; k++) {
                    if (l != i && l != j && l != k) {
                        boolean b = isOK(pointList.get(l), `pointList.get(i), pointList.get(j), pointList.get(k));`
                        System.out.println(b);
                        if (b == true) {
                            pointList.remove(pointList.get(l);
                            n--;
                            stay_into_loops = false;
                            break;
```

However it is generally a code smell when you encounter things like these. Consider refactoring the code because this will escalate into a mess at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Create an exit for yourself in each inner for loop.
Here's a quick and painless solution.

```
  bool breakout;
  for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) 
  {
        breakout = false;
        for (int i = 1; i < (n - 2) && !breakout; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < (n - 1) && !breakout; j++)
                for (int k = j + 1; k < n && !breakout; k++)
                {
                    if(b == true)
                        breakout = true;                            
                }
  }
```

So you see the `breakout` boolean is your ticket out of each inner loop, coz it gets checked in every `for` declaration.
And it gets reset every time the first `for` iterates.